# is it possible to use jQuery Mobile Forms in my webpage

Tags: jquery-mobile

I love the way jquery mobile renders a form, is it possible to embedded a jquery-mobile-form in a table, div or any container in my webpage?, to be clear: I have a html5 webpage anf the layout is done by divs and css, is it possible to include a jquery-mobile-form in one of the divs.

I have been tried to do that but jquery-mobile-form always takes the 100% of the page, I want to use the form in an specific high/with div container, is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could try putting the form in an `iframe` so that it takes up the entire `iframe` but you can control its size

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can adjust the size of this forms like any other div elements.
Just wrap the form in a block element and apply the css "width"-attribute on it.

I created a Fiddle for that:
[adjust jQueryMobile form size fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CCnyp/1/)